# Is it possible to use Google Apps Script to save a doc as epub?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, epub

I know that it is possible to convert a Google Doc file to pdf using Google Apps Script.

Is there a similar syntax like the one below that works for epub?

```
docblob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf');
```

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: The MimeType Enum does not contain EPub so I would say no. But try it.  The worst that could happen is that it will tell you that it's unsupported.

Comment: Unfortunately the only format supported is pdf according to Google Script documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This code will convert your document and save it in your Drive root folder.

You have to enable **Drive API** using Service button.

1. Open the Apps Script project.
2. At the left, click Editor code.
3. At the left, next to Services, click Add a service add.
4. Select **Drive API** and click Add.

[Enable advanced services Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

```js
function convert(fileId) {
  var link = Drive.Files.get(fileId).exportLinks["application/epub+zip"];
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportLink, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  });
  DriveApp.createFile(response.getBlob()).setName("file.epub");
}
```